# Async version of ObjectCache?

Tags: .net, caching, asynchronous, redis, memcached

I'm considering implementing some distributed cache clients (Redis & Memcached) through the [ObjectCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.caching.objectcache) class. One thing I noticed is that all the methods on this abstract class are synchronous, meaning none of them return Tasks. Since the calls to get or put thing in the distributed cache will be off the local machine and include a network trip, I'd like to use Async versions of these operations. So is there a standard cache class in the .Net framework, like CacheObject that supports Async patterns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there is a AsyncCache in the parallel extensions package mentioned by @TrevorBrooks, it didn't work the way I expected. I needed to put/get/remove items from a distributed cache with a Task that could be awaited. So I ended up creating the following interface:

```
public interface IAsyncCache<T>
{
    Task Initialize(Dictionary<string, string> parameters);
    Task Put(string key, T value, TimeSpan lifeSpan);
    Task<T> Get(string key);
    Task Remove(string key);
}
```

I have since been able to implement that interface against several cache providers that offer Task/Async version for their get/put/remove methods and its working well.

[I posted this code on github](https://github.com/paulfryer/CacheSharp).

Comment: One minor recommendation: end the names in `Async` to follow the [common pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Use the AsyncCache class included with ParallelExtensionsExtras NuGet package:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/MSFT.ParallelExtensionsExtras/1.2.0

Comment: thanks for the link, for other readers here is a good overview of the cache class: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/23/10001621.aspx

Comment: After looking at the AsyncCache class included in the parallel extensions library, it didn't quite work the way I expected. I was expecting a async version of Get/Put/Remove operations - didn't find that. So I ended up rolling my own interface, like this: `public interface IAsyncCache<T>
    {
        Task Initialize(Dictionary<string, string> parameters);
        Task Put(string key, T value, TimeSpan lifeSpan);
        Task<T> Get(string key);
        Task Remove(string key);
    }`